# How to get IP address from client's machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the client's IP address in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577496/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc)

I have tried many solutions. But it still show the IP address : 127.0.0.1 . Actually, my address is not that one.

Can anyone help me please.

thanks.

Comment: Your computer? bad news - your local address to ysour local web server IS 127.0.0.1. You can not access the client computer configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound : No, I'm not trying to access from my machine. The web site is at another server. And anyway, my Ip address not 127.0.0.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Request.UserHostAddress();
```

Or

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: No, I tried it yet. But it just show me 127.0.0.1

Comment: Web server same machine as your browser? Will always use 127.0.0.1 when calling local.

Comment: @ TomTom : No, it is in another server, not mind.