# How to Get User IP in ASP.NET MVC API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have tried the `Request.UserHostAddress;` but API controller doesn't have UserHostAddress inside Request.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
IP = ((HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: Is it not a typo "request" -> "Request" ??

Answer (score 10):

I am using the following code and it work for me....

```
string ipAddress =   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: It gives host address

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1773976.aspx/1), a more complete way would be:

```
private string GetClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
    {
        return ((HttpContext)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    else if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop;
        prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)this.Request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
        return prop.Address;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the past, on MVC 3 projects (not API,) we used to use the following:

```
string IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress))
    IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: I ended up doing a little extra research because it felt odd that you would pick up a request header in a server variable. context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] is picking up what is picking up the X-Forward-For request header sent by Proxy Servers and Load Balancers.

Comment: `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` may contain multiple addresses.You should check for that. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348761/790465)