# Get IP address of client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address

I am trying to get the IP address of client machine using C#. I am using the below code to get the IP address :

```
string IPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

But it is giving me the response in encoded format i.e `fe80::ed13:dee2:127e:1264%13`

How can I get the actual IP address? Any one faced this issue please share some idea.

Comment: To me, your example actually looks like a real IP address (although IPv6, not IPv4).

Comment: thats not encoded result that's IPv6 instead of IPv4

Comment: Yes it is giving the IPv6 address. Is there any way where we can get the IPv4 address?

Comment: @Sushri can you check my answer, it works, try yourself

Comment: You can get correct IP Address as mentioned. Try this answer. [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669186/ipaddress-of-a-login-system/39524251#39524251)

Comment: Totally confused by the accepted answer, and the other votes. The question is asking about the _CLIENT_ machine IPv4 address, but all of the answers (except the one from Ramashankar) are getting the server's IPv4 address.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**C#**

```
string IPAddress = GetIPAddress();

public string GetIPAddress()
{
    IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
    string Hostname = null;
    Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
    Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
    foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList) {
        if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
            IPAddress = Convert.ToString(IP);
        }
    }
    return IPAddress;
}
```

**VB.net**

```
Dim Host As IPHostEntry
Dim Hostname As String
Hostname = My.Computer.Name
Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname)
For Each IP As IPAddress In Host.AddressList
    If IP.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        IPAddress = Convert.ToString(IP)
    End If
    Next
Return IPAddress
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your time Amarnath. But I am facing some issue at this line: Hostname = My.Computer.Name; Is there any other dependencies.

Comment: My.Computer.Name is not recognized. Do we need to add anything else added in code.

Comment: @Sushri i have updated my answer Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;

Comment: This is returning the server's IP address, not the client's IP address as asked in the question. The OP is trying to pull the IP address from the current `HttpContext`, but you're getting it from the server. This doesn't answer the question (though it may very nicely answer a different one!).

Answer (score 10):

```
private string GetUserIP()
 {
     return Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];    
 }
```

You may get several ip address, so can split them as-

```
private string GetUserIP()
    {
        string ipList = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipList))
        {
            return ipList.Split(',')[0];
        }

        return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header can contain multiple IP's separated by comma. Normally, the correct IP is the last one. This is because of proxies that add their own IP to the "chain".

Comment: Nice. This seems to be the only answer that actually addresses the question: getting the CLIENT address for the current request (not the server address).

Answer (score 7):

try using this

```
string ip=System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry
               (System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Ronit... this code wored for getting the IPv6 address and I modifed it a bit to get the IPv4 address. The code to get the IPv4 address is :

string ip=System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry
               (System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.GetValue(1).ToString();

Answer (score 6):

In my project it's required to get the local PC IP. So i use it
Please try the below code

```
string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
string ip = addr[1].ToString();
```