# How to get client IP address in MVC 4 controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to get client IP adress in controller. It is working but sometimes I get this error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive


        String IP = "";

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                IP = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        int first = IP.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = IP.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        IP = IP.Substring(first, last - first);
```

Is there any different method for getting client IP address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the client's IP address in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577496/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either of these should work, from inside your `Controller`:

method 1:

```
string userIpAddress = this.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

method 2:

```
string userIpAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: I tried method 1 and method 2 but result IP:127.0.0.1 I dont want local ip.I need external ip address

Comment: If you are testing this on localhost you will receive the looback address. If you receive a request not from the local machine it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes you are right.I tested on hosting it is working.Thank you bro

Comment: These code snippets are to be used inside a controller's action, so this refers to the controller.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Following line of code has helped me:

```
string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress this gives user host address and it's not real request IP.

Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] also returns the same.

Because if the request has been passed on by one, or more, proxy servers then the IP address returned by HttpRequest.UserHostAddress property will be the IP address of the last proxy server that relayed the request.

You can use this string manipulation to get the correct Ip of the request

```
string ipAddressInfo = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; 
   
if (ipAddressInfo.Split(',') > 0){
  `string clientIpAddress = ipAddressInfo.Split(',')[0];`
```

`}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).