# Get IP Address, Browser Type MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I need to get local system ip address and browser agent (firefox,chorme,ie,etc..) in MVC 5. Search google Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] which is not working in MVC5

Comment: `Request.Browser` is what you need to check for browser information. `Request.UserHostAddress` is for IP Address. In both the cases, you may not be able to guarantee the right information, because proxies will not give you right IP Address of the client Machine and browsers User agent can always be manipulated. Let me know if my point helps you.

Answer (score 3):

For getting IP Address use this code:

```
public static string GetIPAddress(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        string ip;
        try
        {
            ip = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {
                if (ip.IndexOf(",") > 0)
                {
                    string[] ipRange = ip.Split(',');
                    int le = ipRange.Length - 1;
                    ip = ipRange[le];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ip = request.UserHostAddress;
            }
        }
        catch { ip = null; }

        return ip;
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348761/4568359

================================================================

And for getting browser info:

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
string brw_info = "Browser Capabilities\n"
    + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
    + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
    + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
    + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
    + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
    + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform + "\n"
    + "Is Beta = "                 + browser.Beta + "\n"
    + "Is Crawler = "              + browser.Crawler + "\n"
    + "Is AOL = "                  + browser.AOL + "\n"
    + "Is Win16 = "                + browser.Win16 + "\n"
    + "Is Win32 = "                + browser.Win32 + "\n"
    + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
    + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
    + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
    + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
    + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
        browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
    + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
    + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
          + "\n"
    + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
        browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx

Comment: (Not sure what to think about _HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR_ and _spoofing_.)

Answer (score 2):

To get client IP Address

```
var IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress))
{
    IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

To get client user agent.

```
var userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like to get Ip address

[HttpRequest.UserHostAddress Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and check out this for browser detection [51Degrees.Mobi Foundation](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/)