# Get client IP address using jquery not iis address without using third party API

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get IP address of requesting client using jQuery. But not by using third party API.
On server side i tried following things.
`Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

OR

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` to get client request ip address
 but wants get it on client side using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

In your server application you would have to create an action such as:

```
public ActionResult getip()
{
    return Json(Request.UserHostAddress);
}
```

and call it form jQuery

```
$.getJSON("http://yourhostname/controller/getip",
    function(ip){
       alert( "Your ip: " + ip);
});
```

But, this is just a simple example which doesnt deal with clients behind proxies. Check this answer: [How can I get the client's IP address in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577496/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc)

Otherwise you have to use thrid party API:

```
 $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
       alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
  });
```