# Getting true client IP address using C# in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, network-programming, ip

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app and I need to get the client IP address.

I researched this and there are two main possibilities:

1. to retrieve the IP using HTTP headers
2. to retrieve it using `HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress`

The problem with the first method is that the IP can easily be spoofed.

The problem with the second method is that if the client is behind a proxy, it retrieves the client proxy - not the client's own IP.

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577496/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc) - this is the best resource I found in SO describing the above problem)

**My question**: how can I retrieve the client's IP address in a way that cannot be spoofed and to get his own IP address, not his proxy's IP - is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: no you can't.

Comment: @DavidLibido why not?, how does WAF firewalls stop requests by ip address ?

Comment: let front end put the client ip address into the request body or url parameters.

Comment: @Sphinx can you elaborate, give an example ?

Comment: @Ben.S the SO item you linked sums it all up