# Given a Uri value how can one check whether it refers the local machine?

Tags: .net

How can one check that an absolute Uri refers the local machine?

Currently I am using this simple procedure:

```
var isLocalMachine = uri.IsLoopback || string.Equals(uri.HostName, Environment.MachineName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

But this is not good enough, because:

- the optional domain name is left unattended.
- the same machine may have several different DNS names
- the host name may be an IP address, which is not handled at all

If it is possible, I would like to have a procedure, which does not generate any network queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this stackoverflow-qestion, especially Eric Rosenberger's answer: [Method to determine if path string is local or remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354477/method-to-determine-if-path-string-is-local-or-remote-machine)

Comment: Isn't it true that Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri.Host) generates network traffic?