# How to check whether the given path is network path or not in c#?

Tags: c#, networking, path, drive

In c#, i need to check whether the given path is network path or not. Consider the below path:
"\Mylapn237\d",
Programatically i want to check this is network path or not in C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method to determine if path string is local or remote machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354477/method-to-determine-if-path-string-is-local-or-remote-machine)

Comment: agree with @Jonesy.  If the code checks for IP and machine name matching the local machine, then it should be sufficient (on top of checking non-UNC paths like C:).